# Sharepoint retrieving data from WebPart containing custom fields

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I've got a site with WebPart containing custom fields.
http://wsscg.blob.core.windows.net/resources/forum/front/aa432.PNG .

My goal is following: I want to add a button below this form and after click, data from it goes to a custom list.

So far I've managed to add a button and a code inline with Sharepoint Designer. It adds some data (like 1,2,3,4,5) to the list that I want. But the problem (probably last) is how to retrieve data from the form.

I would highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to search here: http://sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/

I've found there many useful client-side gotchas.
Site seems down today, but take a look at cached version of dynamic js sp form:
[http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:j97GDCJkwsYJ:sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/dynamic-forms-for-sharepoint/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=en](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:j97GDCJkwsYJ:sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/dynamic-forms-for-sharepoint/%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=en)
where getFieldValue function used.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm afraid that even if I would get those values by JS I can't save them into a list.

Comment: Why not? Just add any JS button and use SharePoint JS client API (feature-rich, mimics silverlight and .net client api). SP 2010 example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx